# Show that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{6((2-n^2\pi^2)(-1)^n-2)}{(n\pi)^4} = \frac{1}{4}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I have to show that

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{6((2-n^2\pi^2)(-1)^n-2)}{(n\pi)^4} = \frac{1}{4}.$$

The hint I have been given is to find the fourier sine series for the function $f(x) = x^2 $, then integrate the Fourier sine series to get the Fourier cosine series of $f(x) = x^3$ where $L = \pi$.

The formula for the Fourier sine series is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \sin( n x)$, where $a_n = \frac{2}{\pi} \int_0^\pi x^2 \sin( n x) \mathrm{d} x$. Now

$$ \frac{\pi}{2} a_n = \left. (-\frac{x^2}{n} \cos(n x)) \right\vert_{0}^{\pi} + \int_0^\pi ( \frac{2}{n} x) \cos(n x) \mathrm{d} x \\
  = \left. (-\frac{x^2}{n} \cos(n x)) \right\vert_{0}^{\pi} + 
     \left. (\frac{2 x}{n^2} \sin(n x)) \right\vert_{0}^{\pi} - \int_0^\pi \frac{2}{n^2} \sin( n x) \mathrm{d} x \\
  = \left.  \left( (-\frac{x^2}{n} \cos(n x)) + (\frac{2 x}{n^2} \sin(n x)) + \frac{2}{n^3} \cos(n x) \right) \right\vert_{0}^{\pi} \\
  = (-1)^n \left(\frac{2}{n^3} -\frac{\pi^2}{n} \right) - \frac{2}{n^3}$$

Hence,

$$x^2 = \frac{2}{\pi} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left( (-1)^n \left(\frac{2}{n^2} - \pi^2 \right) - \frac{2}{n^2} \right) \frac{\sin(n x)}{n} \\
    = \frac{2}{\pi} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left( \pi^2 - \frac{4}{(2n-1)^2}\right) \frac{\sin((2n-1)x}{2n-1} -\pi \sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{\sin(2 n x)}{n} $$

So how can I integrate that to get the Fourier cosine series for $x^3$, and then finally solve my original question?

Comment: you can just $x^3=\int_0^x t^2\,\mathrm dt$, that is, use the integral operator $\int_0^x\cdot\,\mathrm dt$ over the Fourier series of $t^2$.

Comment: @Masacroso could you show me how this is done? thanks for your tip

Comment: you can just integrate it term by term because the Fourier series of $x^2$ in any compact set converges uniformly. I mean you must do $$\frac{2}{\pi} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left( \pi^2 - \frac{4}{(2n-1)^2}\right) \int_0^x\frac{\sin((2n-1)t}{2n-1}\,\mathrm dt -\pi \sum_{n=1}^\infty  \int_0^x\frac{\sin(2 n t)}{n}\,\mathrm dt$$

Comment: well, it would be easier to integrate the previous identity, that is $$x^3 =\int_0^x t^2\,\mathrm dt= \frac{2}{\pi} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left( (-1)^n \left(\frac{2}{n^2} - \pi^2 \right) - \frac{2}{n^2} \right)\int_0^x \frac{\sin(n t)}{n}\,\mathrm dt$$ In general it is very useful to know that the Fourier series of a piecewise continuously differentiable function (=each piece is continuously differentiable) converges uniformly.

Comment: @Masacroso okay so $$\frac{2}{\pi} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left( \pi^2 - \frac{4}{(2n-1)^2}\right) \int_{0}^x\frac{\sin((2n-1)t}{2n-1} -\pi \sum_{n=1}^\infty  \int_0^x\frac{\sin(2 n t)}{n} = \frac{2}{\pi} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left( \pi^2 - \frac{4}{(2n-1)^2}\right) \frac{1-\cos(x-2nx)}{(1-2n)^2} -\pi \sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{sin^2(nx)}{n^2} $$